# Create new folder, named (yyyy-mm-dd) based on next business day

Tags: excel, vba

This in my current folder and Workbook (ThisWB) holding my VBA code:

**\2018-10-18\ThisWB.xlsm**

This is a new folder I want to create from running VBA in "ThisWB.xlsm":

**\2018-10-19\R2**

(only example, does not match today's date)

First folder should be named based on tomorrow's date. Next one should be fixed to "R2".

As I move stuff around, I'm hoping for code that doesn't need the entire folder path starting with "C:\".

When running the code Monday to Thursday, the folder should be named based on tomorrow's date.

When running the code on Friday (or Saturday), the folder should be named based on next business day, which for me is Monday.

Comment: Can this be done? Of course, but most work is up to you! First take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question. First hint: decompose your problem into partial problems (e.g create tomorows date, create a new folder, etc.)

Comment: Good advice from @ComputerVersteher...  kit99 - This isn't a "code writing service" and some attempt at a solution needs to be attempted on your part.  See how to create a [mcve] as well as the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site, and here's a [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will create subfolders in the folder where your macro enabled workbook is saved.

```
'Create the variable "nxtWkDy" for the next workday
Dim nxtWkDy As String
nxtWkDy = Application.WorkDay(Date, 1)

'Create the variable "fldrName" by formatting the variable "nxtWkDy"
Dim fldrName As String
fldrName = Format(nxtWkDy, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    'Set the folder with your macro workbook as the default directory
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

    'Create the subfolders(next workday date and R2) in your macro workbook folder
    MkDir CurDir & "\" & fldrName
    MkDir CurDir & "\" & fldrName & "\R2"
```

Comment: `Workday` returns a date/time serial number, not a string.  You should use `Dim nxtWkDy As Double`

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I don't  disagree with your comment, but we both know that there are multiple ways to get a result, and your way would probably be more elegant. The code works as intended, it may not be the best way, but I like it.

Comment: Had to put \..\ into the last two lines `MkDir CurDir & "\..\" & fldrName` to get new folders where I want them to. And now it works just perfect. Thanks a lot for helping out! :-)